# Areas of interest and expertise of members

Tags: discussion, expertise

It would be interesting if members (should they choose to) detailed their areas of interest and expertise.  Just as a very rough gauge about where the community is at with regards to Astronomy.

Answer (score 7):

I'll start off:

**Expertise**:

Planetary atmospheres, ultraviolet radiation

**Interests**:

Planetary atmospheres, ultraviolet radiation, planetary/solar system evolution, exoplanets, amateur radio-astronomy

Answer (score 7):

**Expertise**:

Software engineering and design, project management

**Previous areas of study**:

Cosmology, black holes

**Interests**:

<sub>I'm going to list interests relevant to Space Exploration as well as here.</sub>

Planetary sciences, colonization, astrobiology, exoplanets, cosmology

Answer (score 7):

**Expertise:**

star formation, interstellar medium, angular momentum transport processes, protostellar/protoplanetary disks, magnetic fields in astrophysics, stellar evolution, stellar atmosphere, high performance computing

**Interest:**

Almost everything (but I'm not really into cosmology, that's all)

Answer (score 7):

#### Expertise:

cosmology, larger scale structure of the universe.
In the near future instrument pipeline

(I'm a postdoc)

#### Interests:

mostly what is in my expertise. Programming.

Answer (score 5):

I'm an undergraduate student, who tends to read arXiv papers he doesn't understand.

#### Expertise

None. I know basic GTR and have some knowledge of the various aspects of astrophysics.

#### Interests (pertaining to this site)

Cosmology and astrophysics.

Answer (score 4):

**Expertise:**

Aerodynamics, Conceptual Designs, Frontend Development, Unmanned Aerial Vehicles

**Interests:**

Everything: The Cosmos, Longevity and Space Propulsion Systems